# What does the phrase "Huge air, rickety loops" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "Huge air, rickety loops" mean in the following sentence (not available online):

*Tilt your iPhone for backflips and frontflips, but be sure to do a perfect landing. **Huge air, rickety loops** – these tracks aren’t for weak hearts!*

Here is a description of the game Pumped BMX Flow:

*Pumped BMX, of course, focuses on bike riding versus motorized vehicles. But the goal of BMX is simple and fun. You need to nail as many tricks as you can whilst riding over several ramps. Keep going until you wipeout, which would mean a game over.*

Comment: "[Huge air](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&iar=images&q=huge+air&iax=images&ia=images)" means going very high up in the air while doing tricks, like riding a half-pipe in skateboarding, snowboarding, skiing or BMX. "Rickety loops" is not an idiomatic expression. It sounds like riding an old roller coaster, but that doesn't quite fit the BMX theme

Comment: They might describe the music. Rickety loops are phrases of recorded music, looped in such a way that they synchronize imperfectly but interestingly with the rest of the track or with each other. "...sound-sources, deploying rickety loops,
wavering analogue wobble, languorous and sickly expanses of pitch-duration stretch" [pdf](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LY9bTMezYOMJ:https://theses.ncl.ac.uk/jspui/bitstream/10443/4890/1/Blenkarn%2520M%25202020.pdf). _Huge air_ presumably means 'lots of space': ie either widely-spaced 'voices', or un-busy music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sports like BMX, skateboarding etc, "air" is time spent in the air following a jump. Generally speaking, the longer a person remains in the air, the more impressive the jump. It is not traditional English to use "huge" when describing the *length* of something (ie the length of time); however, sports like these arose from the streets and brought slang terms with them. "Huge air" means a long time in the air following a big jump.

A "loop" in BMX is a circular track. "Rickety" is pretty much the dictionary definition - something that is shaky, or uneven. A 'rickety loop' would be a circular track that was very bumpy.

Comment: Oh OK. I guess the term CAME from music. Googling "Rickety loops" I get only references to music.